# Open a post of page by native Facebook app on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook

If the native Facebook app is installed on the iPhone. How do I open a post of page link into the native Facebook app from my app. In the case of opening by Safari, the link is same as:

`https://facebook.com/mypage/post/< post_id >`

thanks.

Comment: You can use Facebook iOS sdk to deep link facebook posts. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/ios

Comment: Anything but without using fb sdk?